# Apache Ace feature for Apache Karaf

Tags: java, osgi, apache-karaf

I would like to install Apache Ace on an Apache Karaf instance but I can't find the feature needed. I can see the feature on the trunk but not inside the released distributions.

Where can I find the features.xml required to install the Ace feature on Karaf?

Comment: Why the question should be closed? It's not a real question?...

Comment: It isn't even a question, just a statement.

Comment: @NeilBartlett The question was implicit...I've edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways to install Apache ACE in Karaf. I installed some ACE bundles using the install command on the console. 
Like for the ace-agent feature:

> install mvn:org.apache.ace/org.apache.ace.managementagent/0.8.1-incubator

Although I think I built the source code first, so I got the bundle from my local maven repo, not in any external repository.. not sure, it was some time ago. If you have the jar, you can use file: instead anyway :)